# Facebook Session is not persisting from page - to - page

Tags: facebook, session, authentication

I am having a rough time with getting the facebook javascript SDK workflow to work. The requirement was to offer a "login" link, not a facebook icon. To do this, I improvised a bit. So far it works really well but the session is not persisting from page to page. I am figuring that the session gets set after the login method but it doesn't look like that. Here is login / logout which works fine:

```
 function login() {
         FB.login(function(response) {
             if (response.session) {
                 FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                     document.getElementById('socialauth').innerHTML = "<span>Welcome,&nbsp;" + response.name + "&nbsp;</span>"
                     + "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"logout();\" style=\"color:white; font-weight: bold;\">(logout)</a>";
                 });

             } else {
             }
         }, { perms: 'email,publish_stream' });

         return false;

     }


    function logout() {
        FB.logout(function(response) {
            document.getElementById('socialauth').innerHTML = "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" style=\"color:white; font-weight: bold;\" onclick=\"login();\">login</a>";
        });
    }
```

And here is what I am testing with which doesn't fire:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status == "connected") {
            // logged in and connected user, someone you know
            alert("ok - 5 seconds has passed");
        } else {
            // no user session available, someone you dont know
            alert("not ok");
        }
      });

  });
```

I am also trying "javascript:document.cooike" in my URL box and see not evidence of the FB session.

Kindly advise?

Comment: Could it be this issue: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/q/3871199/3408

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your loading the Facebook SDK on each page as well. For a simple solution that uses jQuery check out https://github.com/xocialhost/jquery.xocialCore.js

The first two functions in the plugin deal with initializing FB and authentication.

Using the provided function you'd do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $.xcInitFacebook = function({appId:'yourappid',callback:function() {

      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

      if (response.status === 'connected') { alert('logged in'); } 
              else { alert('not logged in');  }

   } });

});
```

Comment: thanks but the Javascript Sdk script is in the Master Page of the site (ASP.NET) so it loads with every new page.

Comment: I'd still lean toward the SDK loading after your call.  Are you getting any javascript errors such as FB undefined?